# Entire html document with binding value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get entire html document with binding value using javascript or jquery?
Well, I have html form, and once I click on submit button, I want to get entire html document with filled in value.

Tried innerHtml, outerHtml, html variations, but it only gives html without value.

Explanation: Here is a simple form just to get an idea.

```
    <html>
<body>
<form>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input number="50" name="NameName" id="Name1Id" class=" item-input-text" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Address:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input number="50" name="AddressName" id="AddressId" class=" item-input-text" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Age:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
   <td> <input number="50" name="AgeName" id="AgeId" class=" item-input-text" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

So, once I enter some values(Some Name, Some Address, 35) for those three fields and click submit button, I want to get back following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input number="50" name="NameName" id="Name1Id" class=" item-input-text" type="text" value="Some Name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Address:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input number="50" name="AddressName" id="AddressId" class=" item-input-text" type="text" value="Some Address"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Age:</strong></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
   <td> <input number="50" name="AgeName" id="AgeId" class=" item-input-text" type="text" value="35"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to loop the form elements and call something like elm.setAttribute("value", elm.value) on the inputs, innerHTML on textareas, selected attribs on <option>s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript function in which u use DOM to change the values of input fields 
and call this function on onlink

```
var test = document.getElementById("mytext");
test.value = "My default value";
```

Comment: wanna get entire html with filled values, please see my explanation.

Comment: u can change entire html with dom